# How to use search across multiple attributes in an MUI Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Is it possible to implement a search bar with an MUI Data Grid that highlights the string of the search for elements in the table?

I know there is [this](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/filtering/#quick-filter), but is it possible to convert the current implementation to also search, say, the countries in the table and highlight the string that you're searching? If not, is there another MUI component that can get the job done?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

To highlight cell content you will have to create your own cell for example with the [cell slot](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/components/#cell) such that cell listen to the quick filter value (thanks to the filtermodel selector) and the you can modify the rendering it the cell content match the quick filter